# Clever way to broadcast like a switch statement through a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, array-broadcasting

I have piecewise operation that I would do with a switch in other languages.  Is there a way thru slicing or broadcasting that I can be efficient with doing something like the following?  the data structure is a multi-index pandas Dataframe.

```
def spreadStat(data):
data.loc[data.Pval - data.Tval > 0 and data.Tval.value() > 75, 'Tval'] = data['Tval'] - 500
data.loc[data.Pval - data.Tval > 0 and data.Tval.value() < 25, 'Tval'] = data['Tval'] - 400
data.loc[data.Pval - data.Tval > 0 and 25 < data.Tval.value() < 40, 'Tval'] = data['Tval'] - 300
data.loc[data.Pval - data.Tval > 0 and 60 < data.Tval.value() < 75, 'Tval'] = data['Tval'] - 200
data.loc[data.Pval - data.Tval > 0 and 40 < data.Tval.value() < 60, 'Tval'] = data['Tval'] - 100
```

Seems like this could be a one-liner or some mapping of a function?  Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `cut`:

```
bins = [-np.inf, 25, 40, 60, 75, np.inf]
vals = [400, 300, 200, 100, 500]

# I didn't test, but `astype` might not be necessary
to_subtract = pd.cut(data.Tval, bins=bins, labels=vals).astype(float)

data.loc[data.Pval > data.Tval, 'Tval'] -= to_subtract
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use list comprehension, which is readable and relatively fast. For pure speed you can try `numpy.select`.

```py
df['win'] = [
    'win' if c1 == 0 and c2 < 0 else
    'loss' if c1 < 0 and c2 == 0 else
    'draw' if c1 == 0 and c2 == 0 else
    'other'
    for c1, c2 in zip (df.column_one_with_long_name, df.column_two_with_long_name)
    ]
```